# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, indexof

my function below keeps breaking at var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtch)

```
function isDate(dtStr){
    var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12);
    var pos1 = dtStr.indexOf(dtCh);
    var pos2 = dtStr.indexOf(dtCh, pos1 + 1);
    var strMonth = dtStr.substring(0, pos1);
    var strDay = dtStr.substring(pos1 + 1, pos2);
    var strYear = dtStr.substring(pos2 + 1);
    strYr = strYear;
```

the error message that I am getting is SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'. I took out all of my code after the variables and I am still receiving the same error

Comment: What are you passing `isDate`?

Comment: And what is `this`? You understand that `indexOf` is a function for strings? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the date entered into a textfield and break it into substrings at the dtCh either "-" or "/"

Comment: @Juan: Since you're using `onkeyup`, that means `this` is the HTML element, you need to use `.value` to get its value.

Comment: `this` is the input object. You need to use it's value instead. See @Rocket's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `isDate` function is expecting its `dtStr` parameter to be a `String` (as indicated by the `indexOf` and `substring` function calls).  However, the function is being invoked with an argument that is of type `Object` rather than `String`.  You will need to modify the code where this function is being called to pass the correct parameter to the `isDate` function.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're doing `onkeyup="isDate(this);"`.  This is passing the element to `isDate`, you need to get its value before you can use it.

```
function isDate(dtStr){
    dtStr = dtStr.value;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hu Rocket I added in dtStr = dtStr.value and I am still getting SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined at line var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtch). I placed dtStr = dtStr.value; right after the daysInMonth variable

Comment: @JuanAlmonte: What element is this `keyup` attached to?

Comment: @JuanAlmonte: What does `console.log(dtStr)` output?